# how to run java program as a demon thread in linux

Tags: linux, java

how to run java program as a demon thread in Linux

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help  you
http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution, take a look at [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It's available as a package at least for Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [daemonize](http://bmc.github.com/daemonize/).